# jQuery val() function and file input field in IE

Tags: jquery, file, input, cross-browser, internet-explorer

I have a file inputfile

`<input tye='file' id='funPic' name='funPic' />`

I need to get the name of the selected file,

`$('#funPic').val()` in Firefox and Chrome gives `abc.jpg` where as IE7 & IE8 gives `c:\xyz\abc.jpg`

Why is this? I need only the `abc.jpg` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
$('#funPic').val().split("\\").pop();
```

Mozilla and other browsers don't give the full path for security reasons.  IE will only give the filename when the page runs outside the local security zone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535126(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: And I don't believe any browser is **required** to provide the actual filename either, only recommended...